# Handle touch events in ScrollView Android

Tags: android, controls, scrollview

I would like to implement drag-n-drop feature for Android 2.2. I override onTouchListener for each my control. But all my controls are inside ScrollView. When all my controls are visible on in ScrollView, then dra-n-drop works fine. But when not all controls are visible on screnn and scrolling appears, I can't use dra-n-drop. All events come to ScrollView and only scrollview proceed them. Contols didn't get touch events and as result, I can't drag my controls.
Does anybody know how to resolve this issue? I suppose, that scrollview should proceed self touch event, but then it should transfer this touch event to the children controls. How can I do it? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` to avoid ScrollView to handle touchEvents. Also as Ridcully pointed out handle the touch event in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` resolved my issue. I didn't want to implement custom scrollview. I was sure that it's possible to do it without custom view. And your solution really helps me. But I need to call this method and set to true each time when I process touch event of my control.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [onInterceptTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method. You'll have to sub-class ScrollView and override and tweak this method.