# ScrollView with children view, how to intercept scroll conditionally

Tags: android, touch, scrollview, touch-event

I have a container `ViewGroup`, lets call it **screen** inside a `ScrollView`. This container view hosts a number of other `Views` let's call them **widgets**, and some of them are interested in preventing the ScrollView from scrolling and using the MotionEvent theirselves (for example a pannable image)

I can't figure out the proper event intercept strategy to use. `ScrollView` always processes the event before the children, or the children process the event but `scrollview` is disabled.

I read about issuing `getParent().requestDisableInterceptTouchEvent()` in the child views if this view wants to capture the event, but their `onTouchEvent` is not called, I suppose because `ScrollView` has engulfed the event beforehand. I guess the fact that I have 2 levels of layers (container + widgets) prevents this from working, I suppose the container `ViewGroup` has to play an important part here, but I can't figure out which one...

Can I know, at the `ScrollView's` `onInterceptTouchEvent` level, which widget on the container `viewGroup` has been touched to decide if I should intercept or not?

or...

How can the 'widget' layers **in the `ViewGroup`** get the event before `ScrollView` so I can call `getParent().onRequestDisableInterceptTouch()`  ... or is it `getParent().getParent().onRequestDisableInterceptTouch()`?

Thanks in advance

I've read related questions but no luck ...
[Handle touch events in ScrollView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660624/handle-touch-events-in-scrollview-android)

Answer (score 11):

Well after a night of coca cola & debugging I managed to get this to work. I share the solution just in case it is of interest to anyone, because it took me quite a lot of time to get it running.

I didn't manage to get it running with `getParent().onRequestDisableInterceptTouch()`, I was close, but couldn't find a way for the child widgets to get the MotionEvents they need for scrolling once I intercepted the touch on the parent, so even though the outer scroll was prevented correctly, the inner widgets didn't scroll.

So the solution is to `interceptTouchEvents` **in the children ONLY**, and if the children is scrollable (known property), and the touch is ACTION_DOWN, then disable the scrollview two levels above. If the touch is ACTION_UP, we enable the scrollview.

To enable/disable the scrollview I just intercept the touch event and with a flag filter the event or not.

I did three auxiliary classes, one for the ScrollView, one for the Container, One for the widgets:

This class wraps every widget and, if I call setNeedsScroll(true) , then touches will be intercepted, and when it is touched, it will (tell the container to) tell the scrollview to disable itself. When the touch is released, it will re-enable the scrollview.

```
class WidgetWrapperLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private boolean mNeedsScroll=false;

    public WidgetWrapperLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

  /** Called anytime, ie, during construction, to indicate that this 
    * widget uses vertical scroll, so we need to disable its container scroll 
    */

    public void setNeedsScroll(boolean needsScroll) { 
        mNeedsScroll=needsScroll; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mNeedsScroll)  {
            switch (ev.getAction()) {  
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ((SlideLayout)getParent()).setEnableScroll(false);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                ((SlideLayout)getParent()).setEnableScroll(true);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This is the container, only child of the `scrollview`, and holds the different widgets. It just provides methods for the children so they can **enable/disable** the scroll:

```
public class ContainerLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public ContainerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setEnableScroll(boolean status) {
        if (Conf.LOG_ON) Log.d(TAG, "Request enable scroll: "+status);
        ((StoppableScrollView)getParent()).setScrollEnabled(status);
    }
}
```

and finally a scrollview capable of deactivation. It disables the scroll 'old-skool', intercepting and blocking events.

```
public class StoppableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private String TAG="StoppableScrollView";

    private boolean mDisableScrolling=false;

    public StoppableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /** Enables or disables ScrollView scroll */
    public void setScrollEnabled (boolean status) { 
        if (Conf.LOG_ON) Log.d(TAG, "Scroll Enabled "+status);
        mDisableScrolling=!status; 
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mDisableScrolling) return false;
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement `View.OnTouchListener` in your Activity and add that listener to the ScrollView. Then return true in `onTouchEvent(...)`. Before returning call the `onTouch` of the children you want to handle that event.